# Uploading a file from a flutter app with dio to a remoteserver ends in SocketException: Connection refused

Tags: flutter, ubuntu-server, dio

Iam using an real android device and a remote server (not locally) and need to upload files to the server.

The server runs the latest ubuntu 22.04 OS and is new installed.

All operations with nodejs and socket.io working as expected, except the file upload gives me this error:

" Error: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = h1013496.stratoserver.net, port = 48294"

My code is:

```
 static Future uploadFile({String? filePath})async{
    String fileName = filePath!.split('/').last;
    print(fileName);
    try{
      FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
        'x-api-key':'apikey',
        'file': MultipartFile.fromFile(filePath,filename: fileName)
      });

      Response response = await Dio().post('http://h1013496.stratoserver.net',data: data);
      print(response.data);
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Google tells me that this error happens using localhost and an android-emulator with a wrong ip-address or using incorrect permissions in android manifest.

But all this is not my case, so what shall i do now, is this problem client or server-side?

Thankk you!

Comment: Did manifest file has internet permission ?

Comment: yes even it is not necessary on newer android version

Comment: Then use device ip address  instead of  localhost

Comment: As i already mentioned in my post, i am using a real server and not localhost.